# which is the best startegy to configure the spark application parameters?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Im so confusing on which approach i should used to configure the spark application parameters.

Let consider the following cluster configuration : 10 Nodes, 16 cores per Node and 64GB RAM per Node (example from https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html0

1. Based on the recommendations mentioned above, Let’s assign `5 core per executors => --executor-cores = 5` (for good HDFS throughput)
2. Leave `1 core per node` for Hadoop/Yarn daemons => Num cores available per node = 16-1 = 15. So, Total available of cores in cluster = 15 x 10 = 150
3. Number of available executors = (total cores/num-cores-per-executor) = 150/5 = 30
4. Leaving 1 executor for ApplicationManager => `--num-executors = 29`
5. Number of executors per node = 30/10 = 3
6. Memory per executor = 64GB/3 = 21GB
7. Counting off heap overhead = 7% of 21GB = 3GB. So, actual `--executor-memory = 21 - 3 = 18GB`

As a result the recommended configuration will be: **29 executors, 18GB memory each and 5 cores each**

Consider another example where the cluster confirguration is: 6 nodes, 25 cores nodes and 125 GB memory per node (example from https://researchcomputing.princeton.edu/computational-hardware/hadoop/spark-memory)

the recommended configuration is;  **--num-executors 30 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 24G.**

Question: if we use the rules applied in example 1 and compute the recommended configuration for example 2 the result will be very different. In fact, if we `--executor-cores = 4`, and then we substract 1 core from each node 6 *24=144 thus we get 144/4= 26 executors. after leaving out 1 core for AM ==> `--num-executors = 25`. Now if we want to compute the number of executors per node = 25/6 = WHATTTT? Where is my error?

Answer (score 1):

with 6 nodes, 25 cores nodes and 125 GB , 
if the break down is '4' core per executor leaving '1' core per node. then 6 * 24 = 144 (total cores considered) . 144/4 = "36" executor not "26". if you leaving out "1" executor out then it would be "35". 
so for each node (Node1 to Node5 = "6" executor + Node6 = "5" executor + 1 (we left it out) or anyother node carries 5 executor remaining with 6) like that..

Comment: but they recommend 3o executors, this is confusing

Comment: you can refer to https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/ , the article you pointed do making direction to cloudera post. in case of 25 cores/per node leaving "1" core per node for system process and breaking by "4" core per executor per node utilizes the cluster resource better.

Comment: @Karthick, can you please specify how we can set your proposed configuration through a slurm batch file:`#SBATCH --nodes=6
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=??
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=??
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=?`